# Strange TypeError with Theano

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 37, in <module>
        print convLayer1.output.shape.eval({x:xTrain})
      File "/Volumes/TONY/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/graph.py", line 415, in eval
        rval = self._fn_cache[inputs](*args)
      File "/Volumes/TONY/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 513, in __call__
        allow_downcast=s.allow_downcast)
      File "/Volumes/TONY/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/type.py", line 180, in filter
        "object dtype", data.dtype)
    TypeError
```

And here is my code:

```
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import shared

from convnet3d import ConvLayer, NormLayer, PoolLayer, RectLayer
from mlp import LogRegr, HiddenLayer, DropoutLayer
from activations import relu, tanh, sigmoid, softplus

dataReadyForCNN = sio.loadmat("DataReadyForCNN.mat")

xTrain = dataReadyForCNN["xTrain"]
# xTrain = np.random.rand(10, 1, 5, 6, 2).astype('float64')
xTrain.shape

dtensor5 = T.TensorType('float64', (False,)*5)
x = dtensor5('x') # the input data

yCond = T.ivector()

# input = (nImages, nChannel(nFeatureMaps), nDim1, nDim2, nDim3)

kernel_shape = (5,6,2)
fMRI_shape = (51, 61, 23)
n_in_maps = 1 # channel
n_out_maps = 5 # num of feature maps, aka the depth of the neurons
num_pic = 2592

layer1_input = x

# layer1_input.eval({x:xTrain}).shape
# layer1_input.shape.eval({x:numpy.zeros((2592, 1, 51, 61, 23))})

convLayer1 = ConvLayer(layer1_input, n_in_maps, n_out_maps, kernel_shape, fMRI_shape, 
                       num_pic, tanh)

print convLayer1.output.shape.eval({x:xTrain})
```

It is really weird as the error was not thrown in Jupyter (but it takes long long time to run and finally the kernel is down I really don't know why), but as I move it to the shell and run `python fileName.py` the error was thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in `loadmat` from `scipy`. The typeerror you are getting is thrown by this code in Theano:

```py
if not data.flags.aligned:
    ...
    raise TypeError(...)
```

Now, when you create a new array in numpy from raw data, it would usually be aligned:

```
>>> a = np.array(2)
>>> a.flags.aligned
True
```

But if you `savemat` / `loadmat` it, the value of the flag gets lost:

```
>>> savemat('test', {'a':a})
>>> a2 = loadmat('test')['a']
>>> a2.flags.aligned
False
```

(seems like this particular issue is discussed [here](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2009-December/023646.html))

One quick and dirty way to address it is to create a new numpy array from the array you loaded:

```
>>> a2 = loadmat('test')['a']
>>> a3 = np.array(a2)
>>> a3.flags.aligned
True
```

So, for your code:

```
dataReadyForCNN = np.array(sio.loadmat("DataReadyForCNN.mat"))
```

Comment: Thank you! That is very interesting.